# Facebook: search people from apps

Tags: php, facebook-graph-api

I am new to both PHP and Facebook Graph API.  I am trying to build a app that search people.  There is no login, so I believe that I need to use app access token.  Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
define('FACEBOOK_SDK_V4_SRC_DIR', __DIR__ . '/facebook/src/Facebook/');

/**
 *  Load Facebook SDK
 */
require __DIR__ . '/facebook/autoload.php';

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;

/**
 *  Configure Facebook
 */
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('113868548952926', '9b6d12596769cd590aa4e77781a8f86c');

/**
 *  Get App Level Session
 */
$session = FacebookSession::newAppSession();

/**
 *  Make Request
 */
$request = new FacebookRequest($session, 'GET', '/search?q=peole who work at Ford&type=user');

/**
 *  Execute
 */
$response = $request->execute();

print_r($response);
```

However I get `Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException` with message `A user access token is required to request this resource`.  Does this mean I need login function?  What I can do?

PHP Version: 5.6.8

Thank you